# Page is redirecting to Post listing page on update in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am getting a issue in a Wordpress site. When I am updating a page, it is redirecting to the post listing page without update.

I added the content some time ago, but, now I have to update it and I do get the above issue.

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: make sure you have all plugins & theme updated

Comment: try deactivating all plugins and switch to a wordpress theme like "twentytwenty" does it fix the issue? Active the theme. Still running? Try activating your plugins one by one, if it is one of them that causes the issue, you will find out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the placement and content were properly placed. Only We allow the write permission to wp-content folder

Answer (score 0):

It can be hosting issue. May be you have not proper space. You have to check hosting space and allowed some more space.

Thanks